# TypeORM repository not found in one method but found in another

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Im using TypeORM to connect to postgresql database in nodeJS. Im getting this weird issue where:

```
public static async organizationRelations(name){
    let connection = getConnection();

    const org = await connection.getRepository(Organization).find({
        where:[{name: name}]
    });
    return org;
}
```

works but this:

```
public static async importOrganizations(body){
    let connection = getConnection();
    let objs = {};


    let o = await connection.getRepository(Organization).save(this.createObjects(body, objs));

}
```

doesent.

For the method with save i keep getting error `RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Organization" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?`

Why is it working in one function but not in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing this in mu App.ts

```
private async databaseConnection(){
await createConnection(options).then(connection =>{
  this.express.emit("app_started");
});
```

}

The issue was that i was using chai tests and the test started before app was fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete this line?

```
public static async importOrganizations(body){
    let connection = getConnection();
    let objs = {};

    // Line to delete -> connection.getRepository(Organization);
    let o = await connection.getRepository(Organization).save(this.createObjects(body, objs));

}
```

Comment: Yes. that line just for testing to see if the point of error moves. I forgot to remove it when i posted the code here. Anywhere within the function where i do connection.getRepository(Organization) i get the error.